# Not able to enter values in second textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a searchbox and I have made it absolute and added one more text box on the bottom , I am unable to click and enter the value in the text box.

> Note: Position must be the same, Click for the Second Text box is not working

**Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gowtham1993/Ljg4eax8/42/) Link**

Here is the code snippet

```js
var placeArr = ["Adele","Agnes","Billy","Bob","Calvin","Christina","Cindy"];

function myFunction() {
    let input, filter, ul, li, liElem, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        liElem = li[i];
        txtValue = liElem.textContent || liElem.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
   
}
function showDiv(){
let liList=(document.getElementById("myUL")).getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<liList.length;i++){
 (liList[i]).style.display="block";
} 
}
function hideDiv(){
let liList=(document.getElementById("myUL")).getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<liList.length;i++){
 (liList[i]).style.display="none";
} 
}

var selectPlace = function(ids){
document.getElementById("myInput").value=document.getElementById(ids).innerHTML;
hideDiv();
}

var generateList = function(array, eventfn){
let cnt=0;
 array.forEach(function(item){
  var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode(item);         // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);     
node.setAttribute("id", "myLi"+(cnt++));
node.addEventListener("click", ()=>{eventfn(node.getAttribute("id"))});
document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(node); 
});
};


generateList(placeArr,selectPlace);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput,.myInput {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:absolute;
}

#myUL li  {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: none;
 
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="myInput" class="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" onclick=showDiv() placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
</div>
<br/>
  <div>
 <input type="text" class="myInput">
</div>
```

I have added the Image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your ul tag is overriding the div underneath. So for:

```
<div style="z-index: 1; position: relative;">
 <input type="text" class="myInput">
</div>
```

just add the z-index and position to have it on top. You will have to add in a style to the ul tag though onclick to override it when it is in use.

```
.override{
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

function showDiv(){
    let liList=(document.getElementById("myUL")).getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0;i<liList.length;i++){
     (liList[i]).style.display="block";
    } 
    li = document.getElementById('myUL'); // added this line
    li.classList.add("override"); // added this line
}
function hideDiv(){
    let liList=(document.getElementById("myUL")).getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0;i<liList.length;i++){
     (liList[i]).style.display="none";
    } 
    li = document.getElementById('myUL'); // added this line
    li.classList.remove("override");  // added this line
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgq65jas/

Answer (score 0):

The second text box is being obscured by the `myUL` element. In the `hideDiv` function, each of the `li` elements have their `display` set to `none`, but `myUL` is still there.

Rather than setting `display: none` for each `li`, set `display: none` on the entire `ul`.